# Which edition of oracle is installed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-linux

We are compiling a code which needs 32 bit oracle db to be installed. So i need to install a oracle 32 bit. We have another machine where 32 bit oracle 11g is installed and we are able to compile Succesfully.

I need to know which edition of oracle is installed there (Standard or Enterprise) so I can install the same in my machine.

Additional info:
Oracle 32 bit is just a plain db. it is not installed with configuration or Listner. So i cant find out through any queries.

Answer (score 2):

You have to query the data dictionary view `PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION` to identify the release of Oracle Database that is currently installed.

The below query will help you.

```
SELECT product, version, status
FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
WHERE product LIKE 'Oracle Database%';

PRODUCT                                 VERSION     STATUS
======================================  ==========  ================
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition  11.2.0.3.0  64bit Production
```

Comment: +rahul but oracle is not configured its just a plain db. so i cant query it.

Comment: But you've said that on another machine you have 32 bit oracle 11g is installed. So you have with your db file ?

Comment: So execute this query on that mentioned machine where you able to connect with oracle db successfully and check the version.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more information about database, you can query

```
select * from v$database;
```

for more information refre here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1073.htm#REFRN30047

If you connect to `SQL PLUS` it will say which version and edition you had installed